# CMakeLists C++ Beginner

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw, glew

I've started playing a little bit with C++ and to make it happen I decided to write a simple game engine.

For this purpose, I'm using CLion as my IDE and it works all good but adding libraries is just a nightmare. First I've installed all required libraries like glew, glfw or glm using brew, all went fine. Then I spent almost 2 hours to get it to work on my project.

My biggest mystery is the reason why it works, I've worked with build systems in java, python or golang and everything was always clear to me. However, I have no idea why it works the way it works and I'd love to know!

Here is my CMakeLists file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(untitled2)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled2 ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(untitled2 glfw)
```

Now I have a few questions:
 1. Why am I able to use GLM library without including it in the CMakeLists?
 2. Why do I need to include glfw and glew but not glm?
 3. Why do I need to use ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} and not some name like glew? (I tried different names, but nothing worked.)

btw. I'm using macOS.

Comment: Can you please change your question title? Question looks good in general, but the title doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to remember is that C++ doesn't (yet) have a real module system like newer languages.  It just has a list of directories that it searches for header files, a list of directories that it searches for libraries, and a list of libraries to search for symbols when linking.  The `target_link_libraries` directive just adds compiler flags that add to those three lists.

Now, on to this specific scenario.  Most of the magic happens in the `find_package` directive.  That directive really just ends up running cmake scripts.  Sometimes those are packaged with cmake, sometimes they're installed along with the package you're finding.  In the end, those scripts can do basically whatever they want.  They all have the same objective, to give you a way to add the appropriate compiler flags to use the package, but there are a couple common ways they do that.

The older way is to set variables that you can use to tell the compiler what directories to search for headers and libraries and what libraries to link to.  That's the approach GLEW seems to have taken.  It sets the variables `GLEW_LIBRARIES` and `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS` and you then have to use `link_libraries` and `include_directories` to tell the compiler what to do.  This was the only approach available in older versions of cmake (pre 2.8 IIRC), so while it's not as nice to use, it is still how many libraries' `find_package` scripts work.

The newer way is to create imported targets.  Those targets have appropriate properties set so that any targets that link to the imported target inherit the appropriate include directories and library flags.  This is the approach GLFW took.  It creates an imported target named `glfw` that has the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` properties set.  When you pass that to `target_link_libraries`, your `untitled2` target will inherit those include directories and libraries.

Finally, GLM is a header-only library.  There are no library files to link to, so as long as the appropriate directory is added to the compilers header search path you'll be able to include and use GLM.

---

Since you used homebrew to install your libraries, all of their headers are likely under the same base directory; most likely "/usr/local/include".  All of their library files are similarly likely under the same directory; probably something "/usr/local/lib".  That means that your compiler will be able to find any of their headers and libraries is you tell it to search "/usr/local/include" for headers and "/usr/local/lib" for libraries.

So, to finally answer the question:  Thing's work because the `glfw` target told cmake that it should set the compiler flags to add "/usr/local/include" to its list of include directories.  Since that's the same directory it needs to search for GLM and GLEW, the compiler is able to find the headers for all of your libraries.  The compiler is also able to find the library files it need to link to because cmake told it to look for them explicitly via the list `GLEW_LIBRARIES` and the inherited properties from the `glfw` target.  GLM doesn't have any library files to link to, so there's nothing to tell it about.

---

You really shouldn't rely on everything being in the same place though.  You should be able to tell the compiler about everything like this (note that I haven't actually tested this):

```py
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(untitled2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)

# This will fill the variables GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRES and GLEW_LIBRARIES
# that you can use to add the appropriate compiler flags
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

# This will create an imported target named glfw that you can link to
# to inherit the appropriate include directories and libraries
find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)

# This also creates an imported target named glm that you can "link to"
# to inherit the appropriate include directories
find_package(glm REQUIRED)

# GLEW uses an old-style find_package script, so you have to
# explicitly tell cmake about GLEW's include directories
target_include_directories(untitled2 PUBLIC ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# And the library files to link to
target_link_libraries(untitled2 ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})

# cmake will automatically add the appropriate include directories
# and library files that the imported glfw target tells it about
target_link_libraries(untitled2 glfw)

# You use the target_link_libraries directive with the glm imported target
# even though you're not actually linking to any libraries.  It's just how
# you tell cmake you want your untitled2 target to inherit the appropriate
# include directories from the imported glm target
target_link_libraries(untitled2 glm)
```

Comment: This comment cleared up many things for me!